# After using ConversationReset extra dialog is added to the stack (causing problems)

Tags: c#, botframework

If the user hasn't talked to the bot in a while, I run the following code in the `MessageController` (before calling `Converasation.SendAsync()`) to clear the conversation:

```
// get client from bot Activity 
client = activity.GetStateClient();

if (user.LastMessageTime < DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-ConversationFreshnessHours))
{
    // clear the state
    client.BotState.DeleteStateForUser(activity.ChannelId, activity.From.Id);
}

// update last message time stamp
await user.UpdateLastMessageTime();
```

Note: The `user` object above is our docdb user that we load based on the channelId and userId. The property `LastMessageTime` is set after we (might) clear state.

However, after doing this, the bot fails after any call to Wait fails with the `InvalidNeedException` with message:
`invalid need: expected Call, have Wait`

I wrote some code to inspect the dialog stack in the private methods and discovered that when this code gets invoked an additional dialog is added to the stack at the base of my normal stack.

Normal Frame `0`:

```
Wait: Wait IMessageActivity for Sage.Bot.Dialogs.RootDialog.Entry.Rest have IMessageActivity Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Activity`
```

Frame `0` after calling `DeleteStateForUser`:

```
Wait: Wait Object for Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Chain+LoopDialog`1[System.Object].ResumeAsync.Rest have Object
```

For some reason when this dialog is on on the stack, it causes the above exception.

---

Does anyone know how to clear the conversation without causing this problem?

Comment: Where does this code exist?  ...when do you call .DeleteStateForUser?  (is it the next time the user messages the bot?  or, is this code executed from a timer running on the bot?  what is the user object? what is the client object?  please provide more context, so I can duplicate your issue, and attempt to provide a solution)

Comment: This is done in the `MessageController` before `Conversationt.StartAsync(...)`.  The user object is our representation of the user (stored in docdb), it has a field LastMessageTime which we use to determine how fresh the conversation is. The `client` object is the typical `StateClient` used to interact with the Connector. I updated the code above to make that more clear.

Comment: Are you using Azure Extensions for state (you mention docdb)?  Note: activity.GetStateClient() will get the default state client, not the Azure Extension implementation.

Comment: I am using my own docdb interface, so no Azure Extensions in my project

Comment: Okay,  if you are using your own state client, activity.GetStateClient() will not retrieve it.  GetStateClient always retrieves the default: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/5367ba54b08670a714ab30035ac4316d07be5dc6/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Shared/ActivityEx.cs#L218

Answer (score 0):

Please check out how the DeletProfileScorable clears the user state:
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/497252e8d9949be20baa2cebaa6ce56de04461cf/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder/Dialogs/DeleteProfileScorable.cs

```
this.stack.Reset();
botData.UserData.Clear();
botData.PrivateConversationData.Clear();
await botData.FlushAsync(token);
await botToUser.PostAsync(Resources.UserProfileDeleted);
```

If you use autofac to load bot data and retrieve the stack, you can duplicate this code in your MessageController:

```
using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, activity))
{
    var botData = scope.Resolve<IBotData>();
    await botData.LoadAsync(new System.Threading.CancellationToken());

    var stack = scope.Resolve<IDialogStack>();
    stack.Reset();

    botData.UserData.Clear();
    botData.PrivateConversationData.Clear();
    await botData.FlushAsync(token);
}
```